# jQuery multiselect not showing Validation qtip

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget I want to make the multi-select required in that they should pick at least one value.  I understand that the multi-select is hidden and is why it doesn't just validate but having an issue getting the validate to ignore the hidden and validate the control. here is my  view code.

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItems,new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableDistributionEntities, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedItems),new {@class = "multiselect ", id="mySelect", name="mySelect", style ="width:50%;"})
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedItems)
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $.validator.addMethod("needsSelection", function (value, element) {
    return $(element).multiselect("getChecked").length > 0;
  });

  $.validator.messages.needsSelection = 'Please select at least one email distribution list.';

  jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("needsSelection", [], function (options) {
    options.rules["needsSelection"] = true;
    options.messages["needsSelection"] = options.message;
  });  
</script>
```

This is a partial view inside a  bootbox.dialog so on the send call back I am doing the validation. not sure why it isn't validating that control.

```
label: "Send",
className: "btn-primary btn-xs",
callback: function () {
  var $form = $('#form');
  //Validating the form using unobtrusive validation.
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);

  $("#form").validate({
    // options
    rules: {
      "needsSelection": "required",
    },
    ignore: ':hidden:not(.multiselect)'
  });

  if ($("#form").valid()) {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "/Email/Distribute",
      type: 'POST',
      //Serializing the form data to pass to the edit action.
      data: $("#form").serialize(),
      success: function (res) {
        if (res.success) {
          //Refreshing the event schedule edit screen by navigating to it.
          navigateTo(res.url);
        } else {
          alert("Error occurred while saving.");
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I needed to add the ignore to the unobtrusive validation in order to get it to work. this is the line I added

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
var $form = $('#form');
//Sets the unobtrusive validation to ignore the hidden and still perform the validation.
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });

//Validating the form using unobtrusive validation.
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
```

Comment: The only issue I am dealing with now is that when the validator shows up. It shows up in the top left hand corner of the screen. I think it is because the control is hidden that is invalid so it doesnt know where to apply the qtip validator. Not sure how I can go about moving it.

Comment: I ended up must adding a         @Html.TextBox("ui_txt_mySelectValidator", null, new{Style="width:0px;height:0px;border:none;"}) then in the javascript where it applies the qtip just checking the type if it is mulitselect then adding the qtip to the textbox validator.